# Hooks for custom module

Tags: solspace, module, hook

I'm using Solspace favorites module and am looking to automatically add new entries+comments to the DB in a separate Favorites Collection to mark entries as either read or unread (fav or not fav).

**Basic thinking:** A “new entry” gets added by user (channel form) and after it’s all submitted, write to the Favorties table in the DB :

- Get all members active in the last X weeks (don’t want all or guests)
- Grab the submitted entry_id
- Grab the Favorites collection_id (read_unread)
- Recursively write to the favourites table in the DB (member_id, collection_y, entry_id, time_z)

Now on the front (using Favorites tag) when returning a list of entries – I can check for the existence of the entry_id and member_id - if there is a match I can visually mark that entry for that user as UNREAD (fav) or READ (not fav).

Continuing on, someone adds a comment to an entry. Need to mark it as UNREAD (new) so delete all instances and replace:

- Delete all DB entries where the collection = Y and the entry_id = X
- Get all members active in the last X weeks (don’t want all or guests)
- Grab the submitted entry_id
- Grab the Favorites collection_id (read_unread)
- Recursively write to the favourites table in the DB (member_id, collection_y, entry_id, time_z)

*A member is deleted:*

- Delete all favourites where member_id = member being deleted and collection = Y.

*Members visit an entry:*

- Grab the entry_id
- If entry_id, member_id + collection_y exists then delete it effectively marking it as READ.

---

This is all invisible to the user, I don’t need anything returned simply fired after add/deleting/viewing –  hence I’m informed I need to build a module/Extension combo.

---

Am I correct in my assumptions below that these are the primary Hooks needed to get this functioning?

ADD COMMENT:
`comment_form_end($res)`

DELETE COMMENT:
`delete_comment_additional($comment_ids)`

ADD ENTRY:
`channel_form_submit_entry_end()`

DELETE MEMBER:
`member_delete($member_ids)`

VIEW ENTRY:
`template_post_parse($final_template, $is_partial, $site_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following hooks in a custom [module/extension](https://bitbucket.org/d69/readunread/overview) that requires Solspace Favorites:

**Custom Module: markasread**

```
{exp:readunread:markasread entryID="{entry_id}"}
```

*Deletes the entry from Solspace Favorites table where entry_id, member_id and Collection = true.*

**channel_form_submit_entry_end()**

*Gathers active members in the last X days array, grabs entry_id + writes to Solspace Favorites module/DB for active members array.*

**insert_comment_end()**

*Same as above but DELETES all related entries in the Favourites table prior to inserting.*

When members are deleted or entries deleted, Solspace Favorites takes over with its in-built routines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your on the right lines here. A single extension should be sufficient. The other option is to trigger standard Solspace Fav tags using AJAX requests but your proposed approach would be much more robust. :)